# Plotly Scatter plot: how to create a scatter or line plot for only one group

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

My question might seem very easy, but I am having a difficult time understanding how to create a scatter plot or line plot for only one group of values. For example, my data frame, has 3 columns.
My table looks like the following:

| fruit | lb | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| orange | 1 | 1.4 |
| orange | 2 | 1.7 |
| apple | 3 | 2.1 |
| apple | 1 | 1.4 |
| kiwi | 2 | 1.1 |

I want to create a scatter plot that has the lb as the x axis and price as the y axis. However, I only want to make the plot only for the orange category. What parameter should I use to specify the orange category?

What I have now is this:

```
px.scatter(df, x=df.lb, y=df.price)
```

Comment: Here you can just filter the data before pass it to plotly.

Comment: @rpanai I was actually thinking about that. But I want to make it interactive so that's why I wanna be able to just choose it before filtering out the rows. That's why I was looking to see if there was a parameter for that

Comment: Can you elaborate this? Do you mean a menu where you can select the fruit but the default is orange only?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a user selection dropdown will accomplish your goal. Use a graph object to draw a graph for each type of fruit and show the Show/Hide setting. All and only each type will be available as a type of dropdown. Give the list of Show/Hide as input for the button. Now, the drop-down selection will toggle between show and hide. Please refer to the [examples](https://plotly.com/python/dropdowns/#update-dropdown) in the reference.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

for f in df['fruit'].unique():
    dff = df.query('fruit == @f')
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='markers', x=dff.lb, y=dff.price, name=f, visible=True))
    
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            active=0,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label="ALL",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, True, True]},
                           {"title": "All fruit"}]),
                dict(label="Orange",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, False, False]},
                           {"title": "Orange"}]),
                dict(label="Apple",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [False, True, False]},
                           {"title": "Apple"}]),
                dict(label="Kiwi",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [False, False, True]},
                           {"title": "Kiwi"}]),
            ]),
        )
    ])

fig.show()
```

[image]